# Function Definitions, TypeError

Tags: python, function, typeerror

I wrote the following code. When I type 1-5, it runs well but when I try typing anything like `a`, `6` it returns an error:

> Python tell "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

```
def a():
    a = input("Type 1-5\n")
    if a == '1':
        print("Your abnswer is \'1'")
    elif a == '2':
        print("Your abnswer is \'2'")
    elif a == '3':
        print("Your abnswer is \'3'")
    elif a == '4':
        print("Your abnswer is \'4'")
    elif a == '5':
        print("Your abnswer is \'5'")
    else:
        a()

a()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Python tell "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

It means Python is trying to call the local variable `a`, which is a `str`.

From your code:

```
def a():
    a = input("Type 1-5\n")
    ...
    else:
        a()
```

It seems you are trying to call the `a()` function again to accept new inputs when the previous input is invalid. You can instead loop the call to the `a()` function *outside* of the function which will repeat when the input is invalid.

```
def get_input():
    a = input("Type 1-5\n")

    if a == '1':
        print("Your answer is \'1'")
    elif a == '2':
        print("Your answer is \'2'")
    elif a == '3':
        print("Your answer is \'3'")
    elif a == '4':
        print("Your answer is \'4'")
    elif a == '5':
        print("Your answer is \'5'")
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        return False  # we did not get a valid input

    return True  # we successfully received a valid input

is_valid_input = False
while not is_valid_input:
    is_valid_input = get_input()
```

Notice that I also renamed the function to `get_input` to make it clearer. It also differentiates it from the local variable with the same name (`a`), which helps in avoiding that kind of `TypeError` you are having because it's clearer which one is the `str` and which one is the function.

```
$ python3 test.py
Type 1-5
6
Invalid input
Type 1-5
a
Invalid input
Type 1-5
1
Your answer is '1'
$
```

Comment: @WhoAmI I'm not sure what you mean, but `is_valid_input` is not initialized by the function, it is initialized outside of it. When the Python file/script is run, Python stores the definition of `get_input` (but does not call it), sets `is_valid_input` to False, then starts the `while` loop, which calls the `get_input` function. It might help to go through some [beginner tutorials](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers) for Python.

Answer (score 2):

You are reusing the function name `a` as a variable of the same name. Change the function or variable name, and it’ll work.

Comment: can you give me the reason why function name and variable can't use the same name?

Comment: Because the system assumes the local variable (the variable inside the function), not the global.